# SqlTableDependency for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

in my application in node I run a query every 30 seconds to get data from my sql server database.

However I want my app to be real time, i saw there is something that is called "SqlTableDependency" in asp.net that do exactly what I need.
The package "SqlTableDependency" listens to the database and send notifications whenever the table change.

I want to know if there is a package in node that does anything similar.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can go for EDGE.js [this link](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) which is a bridge between node and c#. Basically you can execute c# code through node code by importing a module called `edge`.
You can get more tutorial stuff on [this link](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1195/using-edgejs-combine-dotnet-nodejs).
I am also looking for a complete replacement of c#.